# getting specific string value from an array

Tags: java, android, json, string

```
String user=database.getUserDetails();
String user_id=user.get("id");
String delivered;
```

in this case string delivered is some unparsed json like

```
[{" delivered ":" 1"}, {"delivered ":" 11"},{"delivered ":" 19"}]
```

now I want to do a check like

```
if(delivered.toLowerCase().contains(user_id)
```

The issue is in this case it will return 11 and 19 as containing 1 so I'd prefer to be able to check if delivered contains "user_id" in the double quotes so as to ensure that only occurrences of that exact figure are returned. Someone please point me in the right direction thanks

Comment: If the values you are comparing are really to be treated as integers, you could parse them as integers and compare the integers instead.  See Integer.parseInt and String.trim.

Comment: they are integers but wrapped between the other characters and extracting the integers alone is a problem

Comment: That's a wrong way to parse JSON objects. You should use some library that lets you get the elements from a JSON object. Don't handle it like it was a simple string.

Comment: the thing is this array is one object of a bigger JSON object which I already parsed so I don't know how to receive and parse an object from another starting from the php code to the java part so I just figured I'd get a string then check for the required integers but as you its not working out so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
    for(int i=0;i<delivered.length();i++) // iterate through all objects in Given Json String
    {
       JsonObject obj=delivered.getJsonObject(i);
       String id=obj.getString("delivered")
       if(id.toLowerCase().equals(user_id)
        {
          // yes it contains ,
        }
    }
```

Comment: delivered refers to this entire string so that doesn't work
    [{" delivered ":" 1"}, {"delivered ":" 11"},{"delivered ":" 19"}]

Comment: @Vine check now